# Using Content Type hub - do updated fields update in subscribed sites?

Tags: field-definition, content-type-hub

The title pretty much covers my question...

I've updated a field in the content type hub - I want this field update to be reflected in the consuming sites/webs. I don't think the field defs are syndicated out, but I'd like to be wrong about this...

If not - what solutions have you used - PowerShell to update fields in subscribing sites/webs?

Answer (score 3):

I had changed a field definition's property and found that the new definition was synced to the subscribing site after also republishing a content type that was using the customized site column.

I did this on SharePoint 2010, and only had one content type that was using the customized site column. In this case I had changed a Date/Time field's default value from a specific date to the None option and was having problems syncing the change until after republishing the content type.

I got the idea from this blog post: [Changing a site column in a content type published in an Enterprise Content Type Hub](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/changing-a-site-column-in-a-content-type-published-in-an-enterprise-content-type-hub/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is no. Fields are pushed from the hub once, and then pretty much left alone. I've got around this with powershell to iterate through consuming Site.RootWeb objects updating field values as required.